# Retrieving user id with socket.io and Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, socket.io

I am using Socket.io and Mongoose for some live validation on an input field (this is a Node.js and Express.js project).

In doing this, I need to retrieve the user.id document from my MongoDB. I have something like this:

```
function inputChecker(ioInstance) {
io = ioInstance;
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.on('userInput', function(userInput) {
        User.findOne({_id: req.user._id}, function (doc) {
            //Do something with the user doc
        }
    }
}
}

module.exports = {
router,
inputChecker
};
```

If I'm doing a normal POST request, using `_id: req.user._id` would work fine, but I can't use it with Socket.io. How can I retrieve the user document?

Comment: what is the value of `userInput`?

Comment: So `userInput` comes from the front end, where the code is written like this: `$someButton.on('click', function() {
   socket.emit('userInput');
});`